# Camunda task process delete

Tags: camunda

AM working on camunda bpm 7.3 with eclipse plugin camunda modeler 3.0.0 am clearing the all war files in webapps  but still in processes it showing the processes how to remove the old task process from cockpit please help me

and my env is :
os:ubuntu 14.0.4
eclipse:Luna
tomacat:7.x
camunda:7.3
camunda modeler:3.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the reference[1] for the processes.xml file. Setting the property 'isDeleteUponUndeploy' to true will delete everything from that deployment when you undeploy the WAR. It that what you are looking for?

[1]: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/deployment-descriptors/tags/process-archive/#syntax-reference

Comment: already deployed process not deleted am clear the webapps folder also still processes are available in tasklist of cockpit

Comment: If you have the war running without the setting, and change the property to true will only apply to the next deployment, because the instances you have running were deployed with setting "do not delete". This was a bit confusing for me at first, too, but it's pretty obvious if you think about it.

Comment: thankyou @jan ,Yes finally i got just am deleting the process-engine.h2.db in th camunda-h2 -dbs and solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Embedded;

if you know which taskId is active, you can get list of them; then delete with cascade true.

```java
    taskService.deleteTask(task.getId, true)
```

or you can give your task DueDate and you can delete with cascade after get your active TaskList

```java
    List<Task> taskList = taskService.createTaskQuery().dueBefore(new Date()).active().list();
    for (Task task : taskList) {
        taskService.deleteTask(task.getId, true);
    }
```

Comment: taskService.deleteTask(task.getId, true) is giving
`The task cannot be deleted because is part of a running process`